# API to detect sample points across a boundary?

Tags: image, algorithm, image-processing, graphics, computer-vision

Assume I have an image that consists of only pur black and pure white pixels, describing a boundary:

[image]

I want to approximate the real shape by sampling along the border and then using some form of polynomial interpolation to generate the  boundary analytically.

Is there an API or algorithm that can generate the sample points from an image like this?

Comment: In matlab you can use boundary function to approximate boundary points. you can 
 use bwboundaries to get contour points see link  https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/boundary.html  https://it.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwboundaries.html?searchHighlight=bwboundaries&s_tid=doc_srchtitle

Comment: I would prefer to use something tha tis opensource, or at minimum not payed.

Comment: you can use opencv library, see findContours  https://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html

Comment: this seems to be extracting literally all the pixels in the boundary, which is not what I need. I need just a small subset of the pixels that is good enough to approximate the underlying set

Comment: read it carefully:  Do you need all the points on the line to represent that line? No, we need just two end points of that line. This is what cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE does. It removes all redundant points and compresses the contour, thereby saving memory.